How to release a port bound to a python Listener in its own thread
In the code below, I'm trying to release a network port that is being listened on by a python thread running a multiprocessing.connection.Listener. The attempt fails with an "Address is already in use" error. What is a reliable way to run such a Listener in a thread, release its resources and be able to start a new thread with a new Listener listening on the same port? And beyond reliable, is there a more elegant way than the repeated checks on the variable self.stopped that I'm trying to use?
import gc
import threading
import time

from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

class MyListener(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=False)
        self.name = name
        self.address = ('localhost', 5000)
        self.stopped = False
        self.print("Object constructed")

    def run(self):
        self.print("Thread started")
        if self.stopped:
            self.print("exit run 1")
            return
        with Listener(self.address) as listener:
            self.print("Listener created")
            self.listener = listener
            if self.stopped:
                self.close()
                self.print("exit run 2")
                return
            while not self.stopped:
                with listener.accept() as conn:
                    self.conn = conn
                    if self.stopped:
                        self.close()
                        self.print("exit run 3")
                        return
                    msg = self.conn.recv()
        self.print("exit run 4")
        self.close()
        
    def close(self):
        self.print("Closing")
        self.stopped = True
        try:
            conn = self.conn
        except:
            conn = None
            self.print("No connection to close")
        if not conn is None:
            self.print("Closing connection")
            conn.close()
            del self.conn
        
        try:
            listener = self.listener
        except:
            listener = None
            self.print("No listener to close")

        if not listener is None:
            self.print("Listener closing")
            self.listener.close()
            del self.listener
            self.print("Listener closed")

        gc.collect()
        self.print("All closed")

    def print(self, text):
        thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
        if thread_name == "MainThread":
            thread_name = "M"
        print(thread_name +":" + self.name + ": " + text)


sleepseconds=1
l1 = MyListener(name="A")
time.sleep(sleepseconds)
l1.start()
time.sleep(sleepseconds)
l1.close()
time.sleep(sleepseconds)

l2 = MyListener(name="B")
time.sleep(sleepseconds)
l2.start()
time.sleep(sleepseconds)
l2.close()

My output using python 3.12.4 reads:
M:A: Object constructed
A:A: Thread started
A:A: Listener created
M:A: Closing
M:A: No connection to close
M:A: Listener closing
M:A: Listener closed
M:A: All closed
M:B: Object constructed
B:B: Thread started
Exception in thread B:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/user/PlayListener.py", line 23, in run
    with Listener(self.address) as listener:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 464, in __init__
    self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 608, in __init__
    self._socket.bind(address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
M:B: Closing
M:B: No connection to close
M:B: No listener to close
M:B: All closed


An answer to a related question was given here. Correspondingly, what seems to be reliable is to replace the close method as follows:
    def close(self):
    self.stopped = True
        try:
            Client(self.address)
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            pass
        try:
        conn = self.conn
    except:
            conn = None
    if not conn is None:
            conn.close()

        try:
            listener = self.listener
        except:
            listener = None

    if not listener is None:
            self.listener.close()


Elegance still to be discovered.
